# c# LINQ how to properly pass a method into the select and return the value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a LINQ query that I'm trying to pass a method into it and then return the results back to the select statement.

There are no errors being thrown but `UpdatedYesterday` contains nothing even through `GetUpdatedValue(int r)` is returning a `yes or no`. Is a way to get the returned value in the select statement ?

For example

```cs
var result = (from r in reportOne
              join l in logs on r.id equals l.id into g
              select new TestReport
              {
                  UserID = r.UserID,
                  UpdatedDate = r.UpdatedDate,
                  UpdatedYesterday = g.Where(x => x.LogDate == r.WorkDate)
                                      .Select(x => GetUpdatedValue(x.updatedYesterday)).FirstOrDefault()

              }).ToList();
                      
                              
public string GetUpdatedValue(int r)
{
    var value = r > 0 ? "Yes" : "No";
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `LogDate ` and `WorkDate` exacly the same? even in second? I suggest remove this `Where(x => x.LogDate == r.WorkDate)` and test it.

Comment: Without more context, it's really impossible to do anything more than speculate. A [mcve] would make it much easier for us to help you. (And I doubt that that needs a join...)

Comment: perform after GetUpdatedValue as it cant be translated to sql anyway ... assuming u not trying to do that, then also make sure updatedYesterday cant be null

Comment: @Seabizkit: if it was Linq-To-Sql/Entities he would get an error

Comment: Can you post reportOne and log classes pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your  WorkDate can not  be the same as LogDate, it's better to use just date difference, without time.
Try this

```
var result = (from r in reportOne
              join l in logs
 on r.Id equals l.Id  into lg
from l in lg.DefaultIfEmpty()
where EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(r.WorkDate, r.LogDate )==0
  select new TestReport
  {
    UserID = r.UserID,
    UpdatedDate = r.UpdatedDate,
     UpdatedYesterday=l.UpdatedYesterday > 0 ? "Yes" : "No"
   }).ToList();
```

but if for some reasons you still want to use your method, the easiest way is  to add one extra property to TestReport

```
public  UpdatedYesterdayInt int {get; set;}
```

code

```
var query=
.....
select new TestReport
  {
    UserID = r.UserID,
    UpdatedDate = r.UpdatedDate,
     UpdatedYesterdayInt=l.UpdatedYesterday
   }).ToList();

var result=query.ForEach(i=> i.UpdatedYesterday=GetUpdatedValue(i.UpdatedYesterdayInt));
```